# How to pass client cert and key for https tests in Protractor?

Tags: ssl, protractor, client-certificates

I want to run https tests using Protractor nodeJS framework. But my tests expect to pass cert and key.

I looked into Protractor, I could not find any option to pass cert and key.

Comment: what do you mean about "my tests expect to pass"? and what browser do you use? In chrome you can add flag to ignore certificate errors.

Comment: I have a strict client auth on server side so I must pass the valid cert and key in order to make my tests work. I  using chrome, Firefox and safari for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `acceptInsecureCerts` field in the capabilities section of your config to get around this. The following example works for chrome and firefox. I'm not entirely sure what it is for other browsers but it will be similar to this.

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  acceptInsecureCerts : true
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found that option but I really want to run tests by passing cert and keys without using `acceptInsecureCerts: true` option.